# TypeError: props.handler is not a function

Tags: react-native, firebase-authentication

Hi there i am trying to build an app with firebase authentication.
in my signup screen once everything is inserted and validated i press my button "register" and i get thi error
TypeError: props.handler is not a function
This is my code for the signup screen

Signup.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react'
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { Input, NativeBaseProvider, Button, Icon, Box, Image, AspectRatio } from 'native-base';
import { FontAwesome5 } from '@expo/vector-icons';
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { alignContent, flex, flexDirection, width } from 'styled-system';



export function Signin(props) {
    const navigation = useNavigation();
    const [email,setEmail] = useState()
    const [password, setPassword] = useState()
   
    useEffect( () => {
        if( props.auth === true ) {
          navigation.reset({ index: 0, routes: [ {name: 'Home'} ] })
        }
      }, [props.auth] )

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.Middle}>
        <Text style={styles.LoginText}>Login</Text>
      </View>
      <View style={styles.text2}>
        <Text>Don't have an account? </Text>
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate("Signup")} ><Text style={styles.signupText}> Sign up</Text></TouchableOpacity>
      </View>

      {/* Username or Email Input Field */}
      <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
        
        <View style={styles.emailInput}>
          <Input
            InputLeftElement={
              <Icon
                as={<FontAwesome5 name="user-secret" />}
                size="sm"
                m={2}
                _light={{
                  color: "black",
                }}
                _dark={{
                  color: "gray.300",
                }}
              />
            }
            variant="outline"
            onChangeText={ (val) => setEmail(val) } 


            placeholder="Username or Email"
            _light={{
              placeholderTextColor: "blueGray.400",
            }}
            _dark={{
              placeholderTextColor: "blueGray.50",
            }}

          />
        </View>
      </View>

      {/* Password Input Field */}
      <View style={styles.buttonStyleX}>
        
        <View style={styles.emailInput}>
          <Input
            InputLeftElement={
              <Icon
                as={<FontAwesome5 name="key" />}
                size="sm"
                m={2}
                _light={{
                  color: "black",
                }}
                _dark={{
                  color: "gray.300",
                }}
              />
            }
            variant="outline"
            onChangeText={ (val) => setPassword(val) } 

            secureTextEntry={true}
            placeholder="Password"
            _light={{
              placeholderTextColor: "blueGray.400",
            }}
            _dark={{
              placeholderTextColor: "blueGray.50",
            }}
          />
        </View>
      </View>

      {/* Button */}
      <View style={styles.buttonStyle}>
        <Button  style={styles.buttonDesign}
        onPress={ () => { props.handler(username, email,password) }}>
            LOGIN
        </Button>
      </View>

      {/* Line */}
      <View style={styles.lineStyle}>
        <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
        <View>
          <Text style={{width: 50, textAlign: 'center'}}>Or</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{flex: 1, height: 1, backgroundColor: 'black'}} />
      </View>

      {/* Box */}
      <View style={styles.boxStyle}>
      <Box 
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("#")}  // for navigation 
        style={{height:80, width:80}} 
        shadow={3}
        _light={{
          backgroundColor: "gray.50",
        }}
        _dark={{
          backgroundColor: "gray.700",
        }}
      >
        <AspectRatio ratio={1 / 1}>
          <Image
            roundedTop="lg"
            source={{
              uri: "https://www.transparentpng.com/thumb/google-logo/colorful-google-logo-transparent-clipart-download-u3DWLj.png",
            }}
            alt="image"
          />
        </AspectRatio>
      </Box>
      <Box 
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("#")}  // for navigation
        style={styles.imageStyle}
        shadow={3}
        _light={{
          backgroundColor: "gray.50",
        }}
        _dark={{
          backgroundColor: "gray.700",
        }}
      >
        <AspectRatio ratio={1 / 1}>
          <Image
            
            roundedTop="lg"
            source={{
              uri: "https://www.transparentpng.com/thumb/facebook-logo-png/photo-facebook-logo-png-hd-25.png",
            }}
            alt="image"
          />
        </AspectRatio>
      </Box>
      <Box 
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("#")}  // for navigation
        style={styles.imageStyle}
        shadow={3}
        _light={{
          backgroundColor: "gray.50",
        }}
        _dark={{
          backgroundColor: "gray.700",
        }}
      >
        <AspectRatio ratio={1 / 1}>
          <Image
            
            roundedTop="lg"
            source={{
              uri: "https://www.transparentpng.com/thumb/twitter/bird-twitter-socialmedia-icons-png-5.png",
            }}
            alt="image"
          />
        </AspectRatio>
      </Box>
      <Box 
        onPress={() => navigation.navigate("#")}  // for navigation
        style={styles.imageStyle}
        shadow={3}
        _light={{
          backgroundColor: "gray.50",
        }}
        _dark={{
          backgroundColor: "gray.700",
        }}
      >
        <AspectRatio ratio={1 / 1}>
          <Image
            
            roundedTop="lg"
            source={{
              uri: "https://www.transparentpng.com/thumb/apple-logo/RRgURB-apple-logo-clipart-hd.png",
            }}
            alt="image"
          />
        </AspectRatio>
      </Box>
      </View>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
    </View>
  );
}

export default () => {
  return (
    <NativeBaseProvider>
     
        <Signin />
      
    </NativeBaseProvider>
  )
}
```

And this is my code for the App.js
App.js

```
import { StatusBar } from 'expo-status-bar';
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';

// components
import  Signup  from './components/Signup'
import  Signin  from './components/Signin'
import  Home  from './components/Home';

import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
// firebase
import { firebaseConfig } from './Config';
import {initializeApp,} from 'firebase/app'
import { getAuth, createUserWithEmailAndPassword, onAuthStateChanged, signInWithEmailAndPassword, signOut } from "firebase/auth"

import { 
  initializeFirestore, 
  getFirestore, 
  setDoc, 
  doc, 
  addDoc, 
  collection,
  query, 
  where, 
  onSnapshot 
} from 'firebase/firestore'


const FBapp = initializeApp( firebaseConfig)
const FSdb = initializeFirestore(FBapp, {useFetchStreams: false})
const FBauth = getAuth()

initializeApp(firebaseConfig)


const Stack = createStackNavigator();




function App() {
  const[ auth, setAuth ] = useState()
  const[ user, setUser ] = useState()
  const [signupError, setSignupError ] = useState()
  const [signinError, setSigninError ] = useState()
  const [ data, setData ] = useState()


  useEffect(() => {
    onAuthStateChanged( FBauth, (user) => {
      if( user ) { 
        setAuth(true) 
        setUser(user)
        // console.log( 'authed')
        if( !data ) { getData() }
      }
      else {
        setAuth(false)
        setUser(null)
      }
    })
  })

  // useEffect( () => {
  //   if( !data && user ) {
  //     getData()
  //   }
  // }, [data,auth, user])

  const SignupHandler = ( email, password ) => {
    setSignupError(null)
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword( FBauth, email, password )
    .then( ( userCredential ) => { 
      setUser(userCredential.user)
      setAuth( true )
    } )
    .catch( (error) => { setSignupError(error.code) })
  }

  const SigninHandler = ( email, password ) => {
    signInWithEmailAndPassword( FBauth, email, password )
    .then( (userCredential) => {
      setUser(userCredential.user)
      setAuth(true)
      console.log( userCredential.user.uid)
    })
    .catch( (error) => { 
      const message = (error.code.includes('/') ) ? error.code.split('/')[1].replace(/-/g, ' ') : error.code
      setSigninError(message) 
    })
  }
  return (
    <Stack.Navigator screenOptions={{headerShown: false}} >
      <Stack.Screen name="Signup" options={{title: 'Sign up'}}>
          { (props) => 
          <Signup {...props} 
          handler={SignupHandler} 
          auth={auth} 
          error={signupError} 
          /> }
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen 
          name="Signin" 
          options={{
            title:'Sign in'
          }}
        >
          { (props) => 
          <Signin {...props} 
          auth={auth} 
          error={signinError} 
          handler={SigninHandler} 
          /> }
        </Stack.Screen>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" options={{
          headerTitle: "Home",
          headerRight: (props) => <Signout {...props} handler={SignoutHandler} user={user}/>
        }}>
          { (props) => 
          <Home {...props} auth={auth} add={addData} data={ data } /> }
        </Stack.Screen>
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
}



export default () => {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
     
        <App />
      
    </NavigationContainer>
  )
}
```

Comment: I think instead of Signup.js, you shared SIgnin.js. i do not see "register" button

Comment: True, thanks for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Signup.js, you define the component Signin which takes props as argument.
Then you export a new component which renders a Signin component wrapped by a NativeBaseProvider:

```js
    export default () => {
        return (
            <NativeBaseProvider>
                <Signin />
            </NativeBaseProvider>
        )
    }
```

But this exported component doesn't forward any props. That's why you get this error when you try to call props.handler in the Signin component.

You have to pass on props in the export:

```js
    export default (props) => {
        return (
            <NativeBaseProvider>
                <Signin {...props} />
            </NativeBaseProvider>
        )
    }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot this solved the issue